# assigning authors to quotes of the day

Tags: javascript, arrays, quote

I'm scratching my head a bit as to how to add authors (on the next line) to quotes.

I have a an array and added comments to ask in regards to this.

```
<script type = "text/JavaScript"> 
var quote = new Array(); 
quote[0] = ' quote 1 Lorem ipsum blah blah ' ; 
quote[1] = ' quote 2 Nullam commodo blah blah ' ; 
quote[2] = ' quote 3 Sed vitae blah blah ' ; 
quote[3] = ' quote 4 Maecenas blah blah ' ; 
quote[4] = ' quote 5 Fusce lorem velit, blah blah ' ; 
quote[5] = ' quote 6 Ut blah blah ' ; 
quote[6] = ' quote 7 Phasellus blah blah ' ; 
// authors:  Name[x] = ' name '; ?
var quotelen = quote.length; 

// Pick a random index number
// Is this how to pick a random number from the array?
// var quotelen = Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length);


// The Start Date (yyyy, m, d) m=0=January, m=1=February
var firstDate = new Date(2016,0,1);  

// Today
var today = new Date(); 

// Difference in days
var diff = Math.floor((today - firstDate)/1000/60/60/24); 

// Calculate the index of the quote of the day
while(diff >= quotelen){ 
 
// Restart the array index if the difference is greater than the array's length
diff = diff - quotelen;
} 

// The quote of the day
var todayQuote = quote[diff];
onload = function(){document.getElementById('quote').firstChild.data = todayQuote} 
// how to add Authors to the Quotes? ... getElementById(' Name ').firstChild.data = todayName ?
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div id = 'quote'>&nbsp;</div>
```

any help with this would be great.
cheers.

Comment: I don't understand what you want the final result to be. Could you explain the desired result in plain English?

Comment: Where are the authors hiding?

Comment: Also, `diff - quotelen` won't necessarily give you an index in the array.  You need to get the modulus: `dif % quotelen` - the remainder will be between 0 and the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing `quotes` as string, you can push an object. Also instead of looping to get the difference, just use `%` operator.

```
{ quote: 'quote 1 Lorem ipsum blah blah' , aurthor: 'foo1' },
```

```js
function getTodaysQuote(quote) {
  var firstDate = new Date(2016, 0, 1);
  var today = new Date();

  // Difference in days
  var index = Math.floor((+today - +firstDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % quote.length;
  return quote[index]
}

function printQuote(quote) {
  document.querySelector('.quote').innerHTML = quote.quote;
  document.querySelector('.author').innerHTML = "-" + quote.author;
}

function main() {
   var quotes = [
     { quote: 'quote 1 Lorem ipsum blah blah' , author: 'foo1' },
     { quote: 'quote 2 Nullam commodo blah blah' , author: 'foo2' },
     { quote: 'quote 3 Sed vitae blah blah' , author: 'foo3' },
     { quote: 'quote 4 Maecenas blah blah' , author: 'foo4' },
     { quote: 'quote 5 Fusce lorem velit, blah blah' , author: 'foo5' },
     { quote: 'quote 6 Ut blah blah' , author: 'foo6' },
     { quote: 'quote 7 Phasellus blah blah', author: 'foo7' },
   ]

  var q = getTodaysQuote(quotes);
  printQuote(q);
}
main();
```

```css
.quote {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0;
}
.author {
  float: right;
  margin:0;
}
.content{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Todays quote is:
  <p class="quote"></p>
  <p class="author"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Gav  when you say *Its not working for me*, please specify whats not working. If possible, share a working sample so everyone can help you.

Comment: I tried putting the code inside script tags, and the css inside style tags (as you do) but nothing is displaying on the page. should I replace the 'print' for 'document.write' ?